# Freezing Hazelnuts, before or after peeling and roasting?

Tags: freezing, nuts

I've got 3 pounds of raw, unpeeled hazelnuts. I probably won't use most of them right away so I'm inclined to freeze them. I'm going to peel them using the boiling with baking soda trick, then toast them. Will it make a difference if I freeze them before or after peeling/toasting?

Comment: I believe you're better off keeping them in the shell, which will protect the nutmeat.

Comment: They're already shelled, it's just the papery covering that they have now.

Comment: Really? <whistles> O.O ;)

Comment: I'd think you'd be better off freezing them in whatever state you'll use them. I would say that if you peel them, I'd definitely go ahead and roast them before freezing. Any water left in the nuts when frozen could degrade the texture.

Comment: @sourd'oh Yep, I agree, moisture is the potential problem. Considering what's been said, I'm going blanch/peel them tonight and leave then on a rack at least overnight, maybe longer. Then I'll toast them whole, then freeze them.

Answer (score 1):

I roast all the nuts I buy and then freeze them.  I have never had a problem with moisture in them at all. I like having them ready to use when I bake.

Comment: Yep, you seem to be in agreement with others too. I think I've got some work to do tonight. :)